# Java. Реализовать иерархию классов Животные

Tags: java, ооп

Реализовать иерархию классов Животные (Animals) и Еда (Food). Животные на делятся травоядных и те, которые едят только мясо. Еда делится соответственно(Для травоядных и для хищников). У животных должен быть метод, который определяет, сможет ли животное съесть заданную еду `boolean eat()` , а так же, созданный класс должен иметь конструктор для всех полей. Я никак не пойму, как можно это правильно реализовать. Для меня вся проблема в разделении животных на типы, и в дальнейшем использовании этих типов в методе. Буду очень благодарен за объяснение того, как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Для  типа используйте поле, для всего остального есть автогенерация в IDE

Comment: Ну поле, это понятно. То есть, я создаю поле TypeOfAnimal, к примеру. Как его правильно использовать в конструкторе, чтобы потом можно было использовать в методе. В конструкторе мне ведь надо указать либо травоядный либо всеядный, и значение будет в виде строки :с

Comment: В методе используйте equals() с травоядным, но проще сделать boolean isPredator

Comment: Всё, я уже разобрался. Сделал кстати через equals()

Comment: Зачем поле? Нужно же иерархию создать! Тип можно потом проверять с помощью `instanceof`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как на Java, но на C# это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```cs
using System;

namespace Food
{
    abstract class Animal
    { 
        abstract public bool eat(Food _food);
        abstract public string name();
    }
    abstract class Food
    { 
        abstract public bool isMeat();
        abstract public string name();
    }
    class Predator : Animal
    { 
        override public bool eat(Food _food)
        { 
            return _food.isMeat();
        }
        override public string name()
        { 
            return "Хищник";
        }
    }
    class Herbivorous : Animal
    { 
        override public bool eat(Food _food)
        { 
            return !_food.isMeat();
        }
        override public string name()
        { 
            return "Травоядное";
        }
    }
    class Meat : Food
    { 
        override public bool isMeat()
        { 
            return true;
        }
        override public string name()
        { 
            return "Мясо";
        }
    }
    class Vegetable : Food
    { 
        override public bool isMeat()
        { 
            return false;
        }
        override public string name()
        { 
            return "Овощ";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal a1 = new Predator();
            Animal a2 = new Herbivorous();
            Food food1 = new Meat();
            Food food2 = new Vegetable();
            check(a1, food1);
            check(a1, food2);
            check(a2, food1);
            check(a2, food2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void check(Animal _animal, Food _food)
        {
            if (_animal.eat(_food))
            { 
                Console.WriteLine($"{_animal.name()} с удовольствем съест {_food.name()}");
            }
            else
            { 
                Console.WriteLine($"{_animal.name()} не будет есть {_food.name()}");
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Результат:

```
Хищник с удовольствем съест Мясо
Хищник не будет есть Овощ
Травоядное не будет есть Мясо
Травоядное с удовольствем съест Овощ
```

---

Смысл:

Создаем абстрактный класс Животные, от него два потомка Хищники и Травоядные.

Создаем абстрактный класс Еда, от него два типа еды Мясо и Овощ

В главной программе создаем экземпляр нужного класса Хищника или Травоядное, записываем ссылку на этот экземпляр в переменную типа Животное.

Эта переменная не знает какое там животное, но из нее можно вызвать метод Ест? который вернет да или нет.

Также создаем нужные экземпляры еды Мясо или Овощ.

И пытаемся накормить Животное этой Едой.

Животное само скажет ест оно эту еду или нет.

Вспомогательный метод check просто выводит результат проверки.